# How to make a square heatmap (overal plot, not the cells)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The `square` attribute in `sns.heatmap` works in weird manner. When I plot a heatmap using random numbers and use the square attribute, it works fine.

[image: Random heatmap using numpy]

When I plot the heatmap with my matrix, it creates the heatmap properly.

[image]

However, when I use the square attribute, the plot becomes a tiny square.

[image]

I can't figure out what is going wrong over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `square=True` means: "show all cells as squares". The only way to fit `7x560` squares into the plot region is reducing the height by a factor of about `80`. In other words: it is strongly recommended to use `square=False` for data that has such a large difference between horizontal and vertical directions. Seaborn isn't doing anything wrong here, it just gives you want you asked for.

If you want the heatmap to be square (instead of the cells), you can use `ax = sns.heatmap(data, square=False)` and then `ax.set_aspect(data.shape[1] / data.shape[0])`.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(7, 560).cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=0)
data -= data.min(axis=1, keepdims=True)
data /= data.max(axis=1, keepdims=True)

ax = sns.heatmap(data, cmap='turbo', cbar=True, xticklabels=50,
                 yticklabels=['Grumpy', 'Dopey', 'Doc', 'Happy', 'Bashful', 'Sneezy', 'Sleepy'])
ax.set_aspect(data.shape[1] / data.shape[0])
ax.tick_params(labelrotation=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: square sns.heatmap]